# Split up a vector into two other vectors, where one of them is parallel to a line.

Tags: linear-algebra

Im asked to split up $u=(1,-1,1)$ into to vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ where $v_1$ is parallel to the line:

$$\frac{x-1}{2} = 2y = z+1$$
$$\frac{x-1}{2} = z+1$$
$$\frac{x-1}{2} = z+1$$

I assign $y=t$ and get: 
$$x=1+4t$$
$$y=t$$
$$z=-1+2t$$

This line has the directional vector of $(4,1,2)$. $v_1$ must therefore be parallel to $t(4,1,2)$. So I choose $t=1$ and $v_1 = (4,1,2)$. For $v_2$ we get $$(1,-1,1) - (4,1,2) = v_2$$
$$(-3,-2,-1) = v_2$$

I check and get $$v_1 + v_2 = (4,1,2) + (-3,-2,-1) = (1,-1,1)$$

This is apparently wrong though and the answer is: 
$$v_1 = \frac{5}{21}(4,1,2)$$
$$v_1 = \frac{1}{21}(1,-26,11)$$

**why?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [project](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) your original vector onto the direction vector, then subtract that from your original vector.

Comment: Okay I get that that is also a solution, but why doesn't mine work? Added together they form $(1,-1,1)$ and one vector is paralell to the given line.

Comment: Your solution does not form a right triangle, which is what they want. If you were to graph your solution vs. the projection solution, you would see the difference.